# Apply function to matrices in an outer product way in R

Tags: r, optimization, iteration

I want to find the maximum of a scalar function

```
delta <- function(a,b) {
  t(f(b)) %*% Ninv %*% f(a)
}
```

where `a` and `b` are vectors with length=2, over a meshgrid.

The idea is basically to exchange a 2-d point (`a`) in design0 with a 2-d point (`b`) in candidate, to gain maximum increment in `delta`. I want to try all combinations from

```
design0 = matrix(c(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1), 3)
# 3 by 2 matrix
candidate=expand.grid(seq(-1,1,0.01), seq(-1, 1, 0.01))
# 40401 by 2 matrix
```

and it should return a 3 by 40401 matrix.

I first think of something like

```
outer(design0, t(candidate), delta)
```

but it seems like outer does not work with 2 dimension.

Then I think of use `mapply`

```
mapply(delta,a=...,b=...)
```

I need something like `expand.grid(design0, candidate)` to make `a` and `b` match. That does not work either.

If they all fail, in the end I may use nested loop... but I hate loops when dealing with matrices. This is already a part inside a iteration.

Below is executable code

```
beta0=9; beta1=5; beta2=5; 
design0 = matrix(c(-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1),3)
candidate = expand.grid( seq(-1,1,0.01), seq(-1,1,0.01))
f <- function(x){
  eta = beta0 + beta1*x[1] + beta2*x[2]
  sqrt(exp(-eta)/(1+exp(-eta))^2)*c(1,x[1],x[2])
}
Fmat = t(apply(design0,1,f))
Ninv = solve(t(Fmat) %*% Fmat)

delta <- function(a,b) {
  t(f(b)) %*% Ninv %*% f(a)
}
```

Comment: You could try to make this more minimal; does ```candidate``` need sequencing by ```0.01```? Then you may be able to include expected output. Regardless,  does the use of ```Vectorize()``` help at all (i.e., ```outer(design0, t(candidate), Vectorize(delta))```). The output does not seem helpful,  but you never know.

Comment: I tried adding spaces to make the code more human readable as well as adding tags. (I still don't understand the goals, but maybe someone else will.) It would have been clearer to offer the "correct" result from the first combination of `design0` and `candidate`. Seems like you could have used `outer` to manage the indices into those objects rather than trying to pass the multidimensional objects themselves.